# Read excel file cell values one by one with button click in C#

Tags: c#, excel

```
public static string ExcelName = "";
            string imagepath;
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               getExcel();
            }

            private void getExcel()
            {

                try
                {
                    OpenFileDialog folder = new OpenFileDialog();
                    folder.Title = "Select Excel file";
                    folder.FileName = "";
                    folder.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx;*.xls";

                    if (folder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        ExcelName = folder.FileName;

                        if (ExcelName.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            textBoxExcel.Text = ExcelName;              // READ EXCEL DATA.
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }


            }

            private void btnImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                readImgaePath();
            }

            private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void readImgaePath()
            {
                FolderBrowserDialog imagepathDir = new FolderBrowserDialog();


                if (imagepathDir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    imagepath = imagepathDir.SelectedPath;
                    textBoxIamge.Text = imagepath;



                }
            }

            private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int iRow = 2;

                textBoxGo.Text = iRow.ToString();
                getExcelData(iRow);
                iRow++;


            }

            public  void getExcelData(int rowNo)
            {

                try
                {

                    string excelfile = ExcelName;
                    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelfile);
                    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                    Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

                    int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                    //int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
                    for ( int i=rowNo;i<=rowCount;i++)
                    {
                        if(xlWorkSheet.Cells[i,2].value==null)
                        {
                            textEnterData.Text = xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].value();
                        }


                        else
                        {
                            textEnterData.Text = xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].value();
                        }
                    }

                 }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

I want to open dialog box for choose excel file and read excel file data one by one with button click, and also a button for go previous cell value.

my code read and display last value of excel file  in textbox and after clicking button it not go to next record(cell value).it is  hanging and create multiple instance of excel exe.

Answer (score 0):

When it reads the last value of your file and you click next, then there is no value, and your else state in your for loop should produce an exception then.

Just put all your cell values in a list and iterate throug a list with your dialog.